# Is it possible to put bower `main` files to specific folder with gulp plugin?

Tags: javascript, gulp, bower, gulp-plugin, main-bower-files

Is it possible to copy `.js` files to one specific `javascript` folder with **gulp** plugin `main-bower-files` ?

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    bower = require('gulp-bower'),
    mainBowerFiles = require('gulp-main-bower-files'),
gulp.task('mainbower', function() {
    return gulp.src('./bower.json')
        // .pipe(mainBowerFiles([[filter, ]options][, callback]))
        .pipe(mainBowerFiles())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/libs'));
});
```

Here is the current folder copying result as separate folder with the plugin

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gulp-main-bower-files` returns only list of files which can be passed to gulp.src().

To squash directories tree b https:/st plugin is https://github.com/armed/gulp-flatten